# weird 3d bar plot for given data using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, covariance, probability-density

I am trying to 3d plot below data, with height being the respecitive joint probability from probability mass function. The idea is to visualize covariance. I had to go 3D because, the probabilities varies for different combinations of sample. The bars or boxes overlap each other in weird ways that I am unable to infer a proper 3d perspective in different angles. If you look at below gif you will know (box suddenly grows over each other at few angles out of nowhere). Kindly help how to resolve this issue. Also alpha is not working.

**Issues:**
1. Weird 3d boxes rendering
2. Alpha also not working

**Problematic output:**
[image: img]

**MWE (jupyter):**

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from itertools import product
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


X , Y = [100,250], [0,100,200]
xb, yb = 175, 125

import pandas as pd
matrix = np.array([
        [0.20, 0.10, 0.20],
        [0.05, 0.15, 0.30]
        ])
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=Y)
df.index = [100, 250]

top = 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)

for xy in product(X,Y):
    x,y = xy[0], xy[1]
    z = df.loc[x,y]
    d1, d2 = xb - x, yb - y
    color = 'green' if d1*d2 > 0 else 'red'
    ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((x, y), d1, d2, alpha=z, facecolor=color))
    ax1.scatter(x,y,color='black')


ax1.axvline(x=Xb, ls=':', color='blue')
ax1.axhline(y=Yb, ls=':', color='blue')
ax1.set_xticks(X)
ax1.set_yticks(Y)
ax1.set_xlim([min(X)-50,max(X)+50])
ax1.set_ylim([min(Y)-50,max(Y)+50])



ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.view_init(elev=30., azim=-50)
for xy in product(X,Y):    
    x ,y = xy[0], xy[1]
    z = df.loc[x,y]
#     print(x, y, z)
    width = x - 175
    depth = y - 125
    pro = width*depth
    top = z
    bottom = np.zeros_like(top)
    if pro > 0: #positive
        color='#B9F6CA'
    else:
        color='#EF9A9A'
    ax2.bar3d(x, y, bottom,  -width, -depth, top, color=color)
    ax2.scatter(x, y, z, color='blue')

def rotate(angle):
    ax2.view_init(azim=angle)    

from matplotlib import animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, rotate, frames=np.arange(0,362,2),interval=100)    
from IPython.display import HTML
plt.close()
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

**Related math problem:**
[image]

Comment: The matplotlib FAQ summarizes this as [My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles).

Comment: despite a steep learning curve, i was inclind to use mayavi, but they are too problematic installing and using in a win 10, anaconda based jupyter notebook. and i did not think i would counter such artifacts even for simple 3d graphs. no workaround possible?